# How do we implement intersection and union in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

So i am trying to Find the sids of suppliers who supply a red part and a green part.

Here is SQL query

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.sid
FROM Catalog C, Parts P
WHERE C.pid = P.pid AND P.color  = 'red'
INTERSECT 
(   SELECT DISTINCT C.sid
    FROM Catalog C1,Parts P1
    WHERE C1.pid = P1.pid AND P1.color = 'green'
);
```

but i have a hard time implementing it in mysql , any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use two derived tables:

```
 select
    t1.sid
    from
    (SELECT DISTINCT C.sid FROM Catalog C, Parts P WHERE C.pid = P.pid AND P.color = 'red') t1
    inner join
    (SELECT DISTINCT C.sid FROM Catalog C,Parts P WHERE C.pid = P.pid AND P.color = 'green') T2
    on t1.sid = t2.sid
```

(I just threw this together but it should at least be close)

Answer (score 0):

Why to go for such complex? Try this, may this work for your need

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.sid
FROM Catalog C, Parts P
WHERE C.pid = P.pid AND P.color  = 'red' AND P.color = 'green'
```

This will give you `join` both the tables and will `SELECT` rows where color is either *red* and *green*. Kind of intersect operation, which you wish to apply.

> As far as concept is concerned, I would suggest (*or what I know*) `UNION` and `INTERSECTION` should be applied when dealing with different tables. It should not be practiced for operation over the same table.
>
> Suppose you have two tables `A` and `B`, then you can should apply `UNION` and `INTERSECTION` not on the same table. That is, If you are querying the same table `A`, and over same column then you can go for `AND` or `OR` operators.

Making a note of the above, you can achieve this by doing `AND`.

Comment: And if you want to know UNION and INTERSECTION for MySQL then read [here](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/92050)